# Server Sent Events (SSE) on Sinatra and Thin disconnects and reconnects repeatedly

Tags: server-sent-events, eventsource

I have made a small Sinatra application to track some of our company data in more or less realtime.

The setup is pretty much like [dashing.io/](http://dashing.io/):

- Rufus Scheduler jobs are used to query a database in a certain interval.
- The query result is returned to a SSE connection stream.
- Clients subscribe to the stream (defined in javascript in erb views) and display the data different ways, e.g. using highcharts.

This all works well, however, I've noticed that if I let the job run less frequent than every minute, the client will disconnect and reconnect all the time. Let me explain:

The subscription javascript code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var source       = new EventSource('/stream/channels-energy');

source.onopen    = function(event) { 
    console.log("Connection opened", event) 
}

source.onerror   = function(event) {
    console.log("Connection error", event) 
}

source.onmessage = function(event) { 
    var data_energy = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log("Time: " + event.lastEventId + "Length: " + Object.keys(data_energy).length);
}

</script>
```

If I let the job run every 30 seconds, everythings works perfectly. A look in the console in Chrome (or Firefox) reveals the following:

```
Connection opened Event
Time: 2016-03-13T13:33:39.625ZLength: 2854
Time: 2016-03-13T13:34:09.656ZLength: 2854
Time: 2016-03-13T13:34:39.698ZLength: 2854
Time: 2016-03-13T13:35:09.395ZLength: 2854
Time: 2016-03-13T13:35:39.493ZLength: 2854
Time: 2016-03-13T13:36:09.592ZLength: 2854
Time: 2016-03-13T13:36:39.674ZLength: 2854
```

However, if I adjust the job interval to 3 minutes, the console reveals that the client constantly disconnects:

```
Connection opened Event
Time: 2016-03-13T13:00:16.018ZLength: 2909
Connection error Event
Connection opened Event
Connection error Event
Connection opened Event
Connection error Event
Connection opened Event
Time: 2016-03-13T13:03:15.912ZLength: 2891
Connection error Event
Connection opened Event
Connection error Event
Connection opened Event
Connection error Event
Connection opened Event
Time: 2016-03-13T13:06:15.857ZLength: 2891
Connection error Event
Connection opened Event
Connection error Event
Connection opened Event
Connection error Event
Connection opened Event
...
```

The client still seem to be able to retrieve the data on input, so the end result doesn't suffer from this. My question is, is this constant disconnecting/reconnecting normal behaviour? Shouldn't the client just keep the connection open, regardless of how often data gets streamed?

Comment: While server-sent-events is also abbreviated SSE, the SSE tag is about a different SSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the client (the browser) will keep the socket open, regardless of data sent.

This is probably because your back-end server is shutting the socket when it goes quiet. However it could also be your local ISP closing the socket. You might be able to diagnose which it is by testing it from another physical location.

However, a good solution, that nicely covers either reason, is to add a keep-alive (aka heartbeat) signal. This is sent from the server to the client, something like every N seconds, e.g. N=50.

For network-level disconnects, sending an SSE comment is good enough. But what I like to do is send a proper message. This allows the client to keep track of when it last heard from the server, and initiate its own disconnect-and-reconnect if it suspects something has gone wrong, i.e. if no data has arrived in over N+10 seconds. (It is rare, but does sometimes happen.)

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer, good to know that this is expected behaviour and how to go about it. I've now found several ressources on SSE and heartbeat signals, so I'll implement something simple one of these days.